# C++ NetBeans: How to link my .o file to my project?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I've bought a class.  I have the header (`.h`) and an object-file (`.o`).
How do I link the `.o` file in my NetBeans IDE ?

Thanks!

Comment: Well what IDE are you using first of all?

Comment: Open your eyes dude

Comment: Lol -- +1. What **compiler** are you using?

Comment: I'm using g++. I know how to link it using the command line, but where do I set this up in Netbeans?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add your `.o` file as an external library.  I was able to accomplish this using the following steps:

1. Go to Project Properties
2. Under the `Build->Linker` options, add a library to the Libraries section
3. Click 'Add Library File'
4. Navigate to your `.o` file and select the `absolute path` option
5. Rebuild

Hopefully this will work for you also.