# How to add object and header files to your NetBeans project?

Tags: netbeans, linker, static-libraries, libraries, object-files

I have some .o and .h files that I need to include in my another NetBeans IDE. So far, I have tried using this approach :
[C++ NetBeans: How to link my .o file to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664300/c-netbeans-how-to-link-my-o-file-to-my-project)
When I open the add library file dialog, it does not show me any .o files in my folder. I guess that this solution doesnot work for the latest NetBeans IDE. Moreover, I am coding in C.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably just to put the .o files in a library.

If you have files foo.o and bar.o create the library named libfoobar.a with:

```
ar cr libfoobar.a foo.o bar.o
```

Then you can add the library using the normal way ( Properties -> Linker -> Libraries -> Add Library File ).